# Video Record with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It is possible to record the content of a div with javascript or JQuery?

I tried API [RecordRTC](https://recordrtc.org/) but it streamed the whole screen and the user has to choose which window to record. That is not what I'm trying to do.

It's my code here:

```
async function startRecording() {
  recorder.innerHTML = "Stop recording";
  screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
  recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(screenStream, {
    type: 'video'
  });
  recorder.startRecording();
  const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
  await sleep(3000);
  recorder.value == "on";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` is to capture screen, which is why it's capturing the entire screen and not just the content of a specific `div`.

Try this:

```js
async function startRecording() {
  recorder.innerHTML = "Stop recording";
  const divToRecord = document.getElementById('divToRecord'); // Replace 'divToRecord' with your actual div ID
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = divToRecord.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = divToRecord.clientHeight;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(divToRecord, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  screenStream = canvas.captureStream(); // Create a stream from the canvas
  recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(screenStream, {
    type: 'video'
  });
  recorder.startRecording();
  const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
  await sleep(3000);
  recorder.value == "on";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I stop the recording I get an empty file.